# Using camel as a proxy, getting "connection reset" on changing URI header

Tags: http, proxy, routes, apache-camel

I would be really grateful for any help on this issue. I am using Camel as a proxy and using processors on the route to log the http request and response to a database.

This is my route:

```
final String proxyEndpoint = https4://targetServler?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false;

            onException(Exception.class).handled(false).process(exceptionHandlingProcessor)
                    .id(exceptionHandlingProcessor.getId());

            from("servlet://?matchOnUriPrefix=true")//
                    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)//
                    .routeId("proxy-route")//
                    .choice()//
                        .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)//
                            .regex("^(\\/?static\\/.*|favicon.ico)$"))//
                            .to(proxyEndpoint)//
                        .otherwise()//
                            .process(validationProcessor).id(validationProcessor.getId())//
                            .process(logRequestProcessor).id(logRequestProcessor.getId())//
                            .to(proxyEndpoint)//
                            .convertBodyTo(String.class)// 
                            .process(logResponseProcessor).id(logResponseProcessor.getId());
```

This works and routes every request, and any non static resources are logged to the database (which is done inside of the processors).

Then I need a second route for other requests / other tables in the DB, but this time the URI has to be changed (it is read from the DB). So I added:

```
from("servlet://?matchOnUriPrefix=true&servletName=AnotherCamelServlet")
                    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)//
                    .routeId("second-route")//
                    .process(handleRequestForSecondRouteProcessor)//
                    .id(handleRequestForSecondRouteProcessor.getId())//
                    .to("https4://dummyuri")//
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)//
                    .process(logResponseForSecondRouteProcessor).id(logResponseForSecondRouteProcessor.getId());
```

In the handleRequestForSecondRouteProcessor I added a replacement of the uri header:

```
inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, newUriFromDatabase
                + "?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false"); // not sure if needed
```

But everytime I call the second route, the connection reset occurs. (Btw, if I call the first route (which works) and then press F5, the same problem occurs).

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:181)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
>       at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:208)
>       at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:78)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I appreciate every idea because I am on this topic for days now. Just leave a comment if any more information is needed.
Thank you!

Comment: Did u find the root cause of this?

Comment: I couldnt find a way with replacing the HTTP_URI header, but I am now using "toD("${header.myUrl}")" instead of "to()" and in my out message I call outMessage.setHeader("myUrl", "http4://xyz") which solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the first request there will be a lot of headers with information related to that request. It's very possible that some of those headers are interfering with your next request. Try removing **all** headers before calling the second route and see if it helps, then you can proceed from there and try to just remove the necessary headers.

```
.removeHeaders("*")
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But as I understand it, the second route acts completely independent of the first (with the only exception being the "onException" clause which should act for both). The only purpose of route 2 is accepting a http request, run through the processor (and inside that processor) read the actual target URL from a database and redirect to that location.